# Stripe Connect form.dataset not passing through API key

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe Connect into an application, and have been following this tutorial: 
https://web-crunch.com/posts/ruby-on-rails-marketplace-stripe-connect

When I load a page with the stripe checkout form to enter credit card details, the expected behavior in having the form available so the user can input their credit card details does not show up. In console I see the following message:

```
(index):1 Uncaught IntegrationError: Invalid value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string. You specified: undefined.
    at new t (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:10860)
    at St (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:19414)
    at Pt (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:19485)
    at new e (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:149125)
    at wu (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:162737)
    at new StripeCharges (http://localhost:5000/packs/js/application-9b4381ae6320422376fc.js:155:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/packs/js/application-9b4381ae6320422376fc.js:265:18)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (http://localhost:5000/packs/js/application-9b4381ae6320422376fc.js:40164:40)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (http://localhost:5000/packs/js/application-9b4381ae6320422376fc.js:41083:43)
    at r.pageLoaded (http://localhost:5000/packs/js/application-9b4381ae6320422376fc.js:41037:66)
t @ (index):1
St @ (index):1
Pt @ (index):1
e @ (index):1
wu @ (index):1
StripeCharges @ stripe.js:5
(anonymous) @ stripe.js:82
./node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch @ turbolinks.js:75
r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbolinks.js:994
r.pageLoaded @ turbolinks.js:948
(anonymous) @ turbolinks.js:872
```

My code looks like the following:

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("local-time").start()
require("stylesheets/application.scss")
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

window.Rails = Rails

import 'bootstrap'
import 'data-confirm-modal'

import "controllers"
import "stylesheets/application"
import "components/stripe"


$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

**app/javascript/components/stripe.js**

```
class StripeCharges {
  constructor({ form, key }) {
    this.form = form;
    this.key = key;
    this.stripe = Stripe(this.key)
  }

  initialize() {
    this.mountCard()
  }

  mountCard() {
    const elements = this.stripe.elements();

    const style = {
      base: {
        color: "#32325D",
        fontWeight: 500,
        fontSize: "16px",
        fontSmoothing: "antialiased",

        "::placeholder": {
          color: "#CFD7DF"
        },
        invalid: {
          color: "#E25950"
        }
      }
    };

    const card = elements.create('card', { style })
    if (card) {
      card.mount('#card-element')
      this.generateToken(card)
    }
  }

  generateToken(card) {
    let self = this
    this.form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()

      const { token, error } = await self.stripe.createToken(card)

      if (error) {
        const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors')
        errorElement.textContent = error.message
      } else {
        this.tokenHandler(token)
      }
    });
  }

  tokenHandler(token) {
    let self = this;
    const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken')
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id)
    this.form.appendChild(hiddenInput)

    ["brand", "last4", "exp_month", "exp_year"].forEach(field => {
      self.addCardField(token, field);
    })
  }

  addCardField(token, field) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', `user[card_${field}]`);
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.card[field])
    this.form.appendChild(hiddenInput)
  }
}

// Kick it all off
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  const form = document.querySelector('#payment-form')
  if (form) {
    const charge = new StripeCharges({
      form: form,
      key: form.dataset.stripeKey
    });
    charge.initialize()
  }
})
```

NOTE: If I replace the line towards the bottom

```
key: form.dataset.stripeKey
```

With a Stripe public API string, the form shows as it should.
Like this:[image]

The form page

**app/views/subscriptions/_form**

```
<%= form_with model: current_user, url: subscription_url, method: :post, html: { id: "payment-form", class: "stripe-form" }, data: { stripe_key: project.user.publishable_key }  do %>

  <div>
    <label for="card-element" class="label">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>

    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert" class="text-sm text-red-400"></div>

    <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<%= params[:plan] %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="project" value="<%= params[:project] %>">

    <button>Back <%= number_to_currency(params[:amount]) %> /mo toward <em><%= project.title %></em></button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/subscriptions/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="w-1/2 mx-auto">
  <h3 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold text-center">You're about to back <em><%= @project.title %> </em></h3>

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="p-6 border rounded">
    <%= render "form", project: @project %>
  </div>
  <% else %>
  <div class="p-6 text-center bg-white border rounded">
    <%= link_to "Sign in to back this idea", new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have been messing around with this for 2 days now. If someone could help, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

**EDIT inspecting form using debugger**

```
form = form#payment-form.stripe-form {0: input, 1: input, 2: input, 3: button, acceptCharset: "UTF-8", action: "http://localhost:5000/subscription", autocomplete: "on", enctype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", encoding: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", …}
Local
form: form#payment-form.stripe-form
acceptCharset: "UTF-8"
action: "http://localhost:5000/subscription"
autocomplete: "on"
enctype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
encoding: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
method: "post"
name: ""
noValidate: false
target: ""
elements: HTMLFormControlsCollection(4)
length: 4
0: input
1: input
2: input
3: button
authenticity_token: input
plan: input
project: input
__proto__: HTMLFormControlsCollection
length: 4
title: ""
lang: ""
translate: true
dir: ""
hidden: false
accessKey: ""
draggable: false
spellcheck: true
autocapitalize: ""
contentEditable: "inherit"
isContentEditable: false
inputMode: ""
offsetParent: body.bg-blue-800.text-blue-100
offsetTop: 177
offsetLeft: 1107
offsetWidth: 575
offsetHeight: 128
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
innerText: "Credit or debit card↵Back $1,199.00 /mo toward Second Project: by Beshore"
outerText: "Credit or debit card↵Back $1,199.00 /mo toward Second Project: by Beshore"
oncopy: null
oncut: null
onpaste: null
onabort: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncuechange: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
onformdata: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwheel: null
onauxclick: null
ongotpointercapture: null
onlostpointercapture: null
onpointerdown: null
onpointermove: null
onpointerup: null
onpointercancel: null
onpointerover: null
onpointerout: null
onpointerenter: null
onpointerleave: null
onselectstart: null
onselectionchange: null
onanimationend: null
onanimationiteration: null
onanimationstart: null
ontransitionend: null
dataset: DOMStringMap {remote: "true"}
nonce: ""
autofocus: false
tabIndex: -1
enterKeyHint: ""
onpointerrawupdate: null
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
prefix: null
localName: "form"
tagName: "FORM"
id: "payment-form"
className: "stripe-form"
classList: DOMTokenList ["stripe-form", value: "stripe-form"]
slot: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: id, 1: class, 2: action, 3: accept-charset, 4: data-remote, 5: method, id: id, class: class, action: action, accept-charset: accept-charset, data-remote: data-remote, …}
shadowRoo
```

**EDIT 2 - HTML form data attributes**

```
<form id="payment-form" class="stripe-form" action="http://localhost:5000/subscription" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="5vPxxBiI2nZRsLQlOi6rDIKI3Wp9ZI7v5w79dfQkgLykkfwPtFhEakD9D/iqrWlhvC3Mgrj6hqVJLY+2/IPrzg==">

  <div>
    <label for="card-element" class="label">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>

    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert" class="text-sm text-red-400"></div>

    <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="perk-1-perk_42">
    <input type="hidden" name="project" value="29">

    <button>Back $1,199.00 /mo toward <em>Second Project: by Beshore</em></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: As you noted that this works when your Stripe API key is hard-coded, this is not really a Stripe-related error, but rather a general issue with managing and passing values/form data around in your app.

Comment: Yes, I understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing it to `form.data.stripe_key` instead of `form.dataset.stripeKey`?

You're creating the form with the following params:

```
data: { stripe_key: project.user.publishable_key }
```

So when trying to access this value as `form.dataset.stripeKey` in `app/javascript/components/stripe.js`, `form.dataset` is an invalid element. Ultimately, this causes to pass an undefined API key when instantiating the `StripeCharges` object.

It might be helpful to setup a breakpoint in your JS code so that you can inspect the form object, and see how to access the Stripe key appropriately:

```
  const form = document.querySelector('#payment-form')

  // New line here. Use the JS console to inspect the `form` object,
  // and how to extract the API key.
  debugger;

  if (form) {
    const charge = new StripeCharges({
      form: form,
      key: form.dataset.stripeKey
    });
    charge.initialize()
  }
```

Comment: With ```form.data.stripe_key```, I am now seeing the error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stripe_key' of undefined```

Comment: I see. Can you try the debugger, or alternatively doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(form));` before it breaks?

Comment: I'll post what I see above

Comment: Got it. Have you confirmed in the .rb file that `project.user.publishable_key` has a valid Stripe publishable API key?

Comment: Yes, they do have a valid Stripe API publishable key.

Comment: Can you inspect the generated HTML, and make sure the Stripe key is present in the form's data attributes?

Comment: It does not seem to be present in the form data attributes. Will paste what I see above.

Comment: When I use ```data.stripe_key```, I see the following error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stripe_key' of undefined```. When I use dataset.stripeKey, the error changes to: ```Uncaught IntegrationError: Invalid value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string. You specified: undefined.```

Comment: The HTML form that's relevant is the one with id `#payment-form`. That `iframe` appears to be unrelated.

Comment: The API key isn't getting populated in the form, so the problem lies in `app/views/subscriptions/_form`. I would suggest concentrating your debugging here to determine the problem,